# pass the url from php via javascript pop-up

Tags: javascript, php

**url.php**

```
<?php
include "../googlelogin/src/Google_Client.php";
include "../googlelogin/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";
include "../fblogin/src/facebook.php";
//FOR FACEBOOK LOGIN//
    $fbconfig['appid' ]     = "329433909112888";
    $fbconfig['secret']     = "ca2bdc9990b0b2ad0763abcka79dce60c91f";
    $fbconfig['baseurl']    = "http://localhost/sbs/fblogin/index.php?rd=hm";
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
        'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
        'baseurl'=>$fbconfig['baseurl'], 
        'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array('redirect_uri'=>$fbconfig['baseurl'], 
        'scope'  =>            'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,   user_hometown,user_photos ,user_work_history',
    )
    );
//FOR GOOGLE LOGIN//
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google UserInfo PHP Starter Application");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
    $client->setClientId('777637661406-cp7kekelp1l5i0se9f576sqf36a0q4lc.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('uztEmqG1CFt06752lqtRZjZ-');   
    $client->setState('hm');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/sbs/googlelogin/index.php');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyD3HiHElDciE6Pb5UfZtDdNWe_kiKNk6rg');
    $oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    ?>
```

**I want to pass the FACEBOOK , TWITTER AND GOOGLE url in via java script in the pop up . I know the PHP part but I don't know the JS part**

**pop.js**

```
function sin(){
    var lbox = new LadduBox();
    lbox.init({"width":495, "height":242, "HTML":'<div style="width:495px; height:242px; background-color:#ffffff; border:2px solid orange;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="485" height="152" style="font-family:arial; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;"><tr><td align="right" colspan="3"><img src="images/untitled-1.png" style="margin:10px; cursor:pointer;" id="btnClose"/></td></tr><tr><td height="30" colspan="3"> <div style="font-family:arial; font-size:20px; color:#ff6c00; padding-left:200px;">SIGN IN</div></td></tr><tr><td><div style="margin:10px; font-size:14px;">EMAIL<br><input type="text"/></div><br><div style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:-10px; font-size:14px;">PASSWORD<br><input type="text"/></div></td><td><img src="images/orbar.png" /></td><td align="center"><img src="images/redfb.png" style="margin-bottom:7px;"/><br><img src="images/redgoogle.png" style="margin-bottom:7px;"/><br><img src="images/redtwitter.png" /></td></tr></div>', 'btnCloseId':'#btnClose'});
    lbox.fire();
}
```

**When the user click on the sign-in button , this pop-up will show . I want FACEBOOK , TWITTER AND GOOGLE URL in the pop-up but i don't know how to pass it in javascript .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"When the user click on the sign-in button, this pop-up will show":
```

Now, the popup code will be inside a PHP file. Include url.php in this file at top, then you can access those $authUrl or $loginUrl anywhere in this file.

Comment: But i m working on a website and I have to include url.php in the whole pages . and it will create a problem for my registration.php page

Comment: did not get you. Wherever you want fb/google login buttons to appear, include url.php in those files

Comment: but how v can I add my php url in javascript pop-up

Comment: <script src="./js/pop.js"></script>           I am adding pop,js like this

Comment: How are you calling your popup code? I mean how do you diplay a popup?

Comment: <font class="ftxt"><a href="#" onclick="sin();" class="stxtcolor">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign in</a> or</font>     I am calling by this way

Answer (score 0):

Now, in your sin(), you have HTML inside your lbox.init. There you can put these urls as below. BUT, REMOVE sin() FROM INSIDE YOUR JS FILE, AND PUT IT IN THE PHP FILE IN HEAD SECTION. Because, JS file cannot have PHP code.

```
<div style="width:495px; height:242px; background-color:#ffffff; border:2px solid orange;"><a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Facebook Login</a><a href="<?php echo $authUrl; ?>">Google Login</a></div>
```

Just an example, you can put this anywhere you want within the html. If you want to put PHP inside .js file, you have to do something like below:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js

AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js

<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Add the above code in .htaccess file and run php inside js files

Comment: I have never used this type of code in my life , I am new to this field

Comment: well, then just put the sin() function directly inside php's head section, so that you can include php code wherever you want.